# Extract amount for the minimum date in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Very basic: I have a table with dates, account and amount done by a particular account on that date. I am stuck on a very basic problem - get the amount for the minimum date per account.

Input:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

If I do the query below it obviously returns the grouping by the amount, too.

```
SELECT account_ref         AS account_alias, 
       Min(timestamp_made) AS reg_date, 
       amount 
FROM   stg_payment_mysql 
GROUP  BY account_ref, 
          amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most performant way to do this would be to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account) account, date, amount
FROM stg_payment_mysql
ORDER BY account, date;
```

A more general ANSI SQL approach to this would use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT account, date, amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM stg_payment_mysql
)

SELECT account, date, amount
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY account;
```

Comment: I hope one day I will be able to contribute to Stack, not only ask. Thank you, Tim!

Comment: just one more question. If I also have a list of accounts to choose from - SELECT DISTINCT ON (trim(leading '0' from account_ref)) account_ref, timestamp_made, amount
FROM stg_payment_mysql
ORDER BY trim(leading '0' from account_ref), timestamp_made
where trim(leading '0' from account_ref) in (....)

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.  Do you have one?

Comment: Never mind, I used your 2nd query. But the question was about selecting from a subset of accounts. I added it to WHERE