# Extract amount for the minimum date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've already asked this question for PostgreSQL at [Extract amount for the minimum date in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968257/extract-amount-for-the-minimum-date-in-postgres/55968300#55968300). In essence, I need to get the amount for the minimum date per account.
I've tried

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT amount, account, min(date)
    FROM new_schema.stg_payment_mysql GROUP BY account
) A INNER JOIN new_schema.stg_payment_mysql  B USING (account,date)
```

But got 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'date' in 'from clause'   0.781 sec'.

If I add new_schema.stg_payment_mysql before date, I'll get 'Error code: 1064'.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT amount, account, min(date) date
    FROM new_schema.stg_payment_mysql GROUB BY account
```

But the amount was not picked correctly. I feel that the first query is correct but I don't understand the error.

Comment: For your 1st query you need an alias for `min(date)` like `min(date) as date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is nearly correct. You forgot to alias your min(date)

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM
  (
    SELECT account, min(`date`) as mindate
    FROM new_schema.stg_payment_mysql       
    GROUP BY account
  ) A 
  INNER JOIN 
  new_schema.stg_payment_mysql  B
  ON a.account = b.account and b.`date` =  a.mindate
```

I've renamed date as mindate for two reasons- one to avoid naming a column a reserved word and two, to make it more obvious what the data flow is and how the query is working

You do not need to select amount in A either; it will come from b

Comment: I've already posted today about the dirty data and that I need to use trim within trim. So, if I modify your query to ```SELECT B.* 
FROM
  (
    SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(trim)) as account_ref_trimmed, min(`date`) as mindate
    FROM new_schema.stg_payment_mysql       
    GROUP BY account
  ) A 
  INNER JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(trim)) as account_ref_trimmed, date, amount
    FROM new_schema.stg_payment_mysql       
  ) B
  ON A.account_ref_trimmed= B.account_ref_trimmed and B.`date` =  A.mindate``` it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Keep in mind that this will select ties in cases where min date per group is the same as the topicstarter didnt provided information what to do in those cases..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, do you mean when the payment date is the same? I have a timestamp in the original database with hh:mm:ss, so the probability that two payments hit the account in the same second is low.

Comment: @eponkratova "I've already posted today" - it's not something anyone would check for to be honest, your question is supposed to stand alone and without reference to any other question, esp if you don't mention it and link it- we cant read minds and I'm not personally a 24h service who tracks every sql question, sorry. Also *"if I modify your query it doesn't work correctly"* - are you asking me to take responsibility for that? By way of assistance I offer that it looks like you forgot to trim your group by, but please don't ever complain to someone after *you* broke their code

Comment: @CaiusJard, I understand and apologize! I need to go through the data, I feel that your query is correct but what is incorrect is data caused by what Raymond described actually. It should not be that two payments hit the account unless, it is a system failure. So, I got payments for one account with identical hh:mm:ss which technically is not possible.

Comment: It may be better to consider a data model that has an incrementing sequence number per account payment, so you can be certain of having only one minimum. Systems that rely on "only one of these things happening every so often so the date column should be fine" usually succumb to something daft like a user double clicking, a delay in processing the first event on the UI and then two events filing in the same millisecond .. suffice to say, a correctly set up incrementing number should cope with even those